# What is a more efficient way in Python to return list elements which are not in a second list?

Tags: python

Is there a faster way to do this in python?

```
[f for f in list_1 if not f in list_2]
```

list_1 and list_2 both consist of about 120.000 strings. It takes about 4 minutes to generate the new list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you put `list_2` into a `set`, it should make the containment checking a lot quicker:

```
s = set(list_2)
[f for f in list_1 if not f in s]
```

This is because `x in list` is an O(n) check, while `x in set` is constant-time.

Another way is to use set-difference:

```
list(set(list_1).difference(set(list_2)))
```

However, this probably won't be faster than the first way - also, it'll eliminate duplicates from `list_1` which you may not want.

Comment: You should transform `list_2` to a `set` **beforehand**, not in the list comprehension. Otherwise you convert it into a set everytime, and this is not really speeding up things ;)

Comment: putting list_2 in a set improved list generation time from 233.66 seconds to 0.07 seconds! But as Felix Kling said: I had to transform to a set beforehand. list(set(list_1).difference(set(list_2)))
 took 0.12 seconds and would also fit my use.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you want to do with the new list, it might be sufficient if you do some kind of lazy evaluation with [`itertools.ifilter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) (so you don't spent time, building the new list beforehand, but you should transform `list_2` to a `set` before in any case, so lookup is `O(1)`):

```
import itertools:
set_2 = set(list_2)

for f in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x not in set_2, list_1):
    # do something with f
```

Comment: This worked great, and shaved list generation from from 233.66 seconds to 0.09 seconds!